# Deployment of flask app (that uses tensorflow) fails on render

Tags: docker, tensorflow, flask, deployment, render.com

I have a [github repo](https://github.com/aditdesai/ai-dermatologist-backend) containing a flask app that loads a .h5 model and makes an inference using it using tensorflow. Repo also has a dockerfile. When I build a docker image and container on local machine, everything works fine. I am trying to deploy this api on render using my github repo and a Docker runtime. The deployment fails. These are the logs:

[Error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm7N3.png)

Deployment fails right after a few tensorflow warnings that are thrown normally when testing on local machine as well but the code runs just fine since they are just warnings. This might not be the reason of the deployment failing but it does fail right after these warnings. What is the solution to this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think the warning is the problem here, it `model_from_scratch.h5` , noticed that model weights give an error when run between os. try building the model(h5) in docker and that is way to debug it. NOte: when i tried you program on mac, i get this error `File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 102, in h5py.h5f.open
OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)`